# Does using an initializer list in a loop work? If not, how does it fail and why?

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

The answers to [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/26100/maximum-of-three-values-in-c) imply that using an initializer list in a loop or with "unknown data" wouldn't work. They don't say why, or how it would fail.

IE, doing this: (this is a nonsense operation, but shows that the contents of the list would change as the loop progresses)

```
std::vector<float> vec;
// Assume vec is filled with some useful data

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{ 
  for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) 
  {
    for(int k = 0; k < 10; k++) 
    {
      result = std::max({vec[i], vec[j], vec[k]});
      // do something with result...
    }
  }
}
```

I have code that uses initializer lists to get the max of 3 or more elements very frequently. It *seems* like things are working, but I am not sure if they are or not.

I'd like to understand if it works. If not, how it fails and why.

I've used a very heavy set of warnings, nothing has ever reported "warning: may be using initializer list incorrectly" or so-on.

Comment: I'm not sure where in the linked question it seems to imply it wouldn't work.  This code is fine as long as the indices are in bounds.

Comment: Yuushi's answer states: "If the data changes at runtime, store it in a container and use max_element". The second answer also states right away "Assuming you have an unknown set of data, you can always place it in an array / vector / list and run..." Both imply that if the data changes, it won't work. Was I just misreading it?

Comment: What they are saying is that if you need to get the data at run time then you need to use some other container.  Techinally you're not getting the data at run time because you are coding `std::max({vec[i], vec[j], vec[k]})` into the program.  You can't use a `std::initializer_list` to get data from a user, but you can build one from data from the user after you have it.  Make sense?

Comment: I think so, but it feels odd that they made that distinction. A vector can't get data from a user, nor can an int, nor can any other storage or container. For that you need things like stdin stream or file reading, which then, ultimately store in something else. I don't see how that separates initializer lists from anything else.

Comment: vectors,arrays, ect are writable.  You can add data to them.  `std::initiliazer_list` is not.  Once you create one, its size and the value of the elements inside it are constant.  This is why you can't use it to get input.  You can only create one and pass it around to be read from.

Comment: @TylerShellberg In the linked question, they say to use `max_element` when the *number* of element changes. For example, if you don't know if you will have 3 or 4 values to put in the initializer list, then you cannot use `max`. In your case, you seem to know that it will always be 3 elements, which works with `max` even if the value of the 3 elements changes at runtime.

Comment: Oh, that makes much more sense now. Thank you both for the clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The answers to this question imply that using an initializer list in a loop or with "unknown data" wouldn't work.

This is a misinterpretation of what was said, due to an omitted word. [The statement you're talking about](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/26100/maximum-of-three-values-in-c#comment40430_26101) was in response to this comment:

> How would you make this work if the data is generated in a loop, or the **number of data changes at runtime**?

Emphasis added. So when the person says:

> If the data changes at runtime, ...

The response simply omitted the "number" part, since it's a direct response to the previous comment.

Braced-init-lists can contain arbitrary numbers of items, but the number of items in the list *must* be defined at compile-time.